# Have the Prador ever experimented with Jain technology?

Tags: polity-universe, polity-agent

In Neal Asher's Polity universe, humans and AI experiment with Jain technology, usually with devastatingly bad results.
Have the Prador ever experimented with Jain tech? And in which books?

Comment: Are you excluding the events of the Orbus et al books as not fitting your criteria?

Comment: @Moo anything happily accepted.